# OpenCL : internal deadlock in multi-thread environment since driver update (Nvidia)

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencl, nvidia

I work on an OpenCL 3.0 application on Windows using the Khronos SDK, that consist in processing a lot of data stored on the drive using the GPU.
To do so, I use several CPU threads that read from the drive, process, send to the GPU and get the result back to write it on the drive. For more than a year, I used this code without any issue, but after recently updating my nvidia GPU driver (from version 460 something to the latest, 517.xx), the program suddenly does not work anymore. I tried a few older drivers in the 5XX range but none changed this behavior.

After looking a bit into what caused this, I discovered that OpenCL calls lock (even ones that should be non-blocking) and never return.
If all calls are done on a single thread, everything's fine, but any subsequent thread will never return from its first call.

As a simple example, just creating a few threads that create each one an OpenCL queue, the first one to execute will work fine, but all others will never return from the clCreateCommandQueue call.

I tested it on two PC, with a GTX1650 and an RTX3070ti, and after a week of trying to figure out a solution and searching online for a similar issue, I found absolutely nothing.

Thanks for reading me, if anyone either has an idea of what could be the issue or can attest that I'm not the only one confronted with it?

Thanks in advance!

**TLDR :** OpenCL with any recent Nvidia driver cause my clCreateCommandQueue (and other cl calls) to never return if called from more than one CPU thread.

Comment: any chance of a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

I have a code example here.
It is not that minimal because I only get the behavior described by eba04348 if an ocl error occurs in the cl context before.
I filed a bug already to nvidia about this.

```
#include <iostream>

#define CL_HPP_MINIMUM_OPENCL_VERSION 110
#define CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 110

// https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-CLHPP
#include "opencl.hpp"

#include <vector>
#include <thread>

struct DeviceData
{
    cl::Context mContextCL;
    cl::Program mProgramCL;
    cl::Kernel mKernelCL;
    cl::CommandQueue mQueueCL;
    std::vector<cl::Buffer> mBufferListCL;
    int static constexpr n = 10000;
};

/*! Please do not use in production code!
 *
 * @param context produce error in this context
 * @param device related to context
 * @return this has to return false
 */
bool produceError(cl::Context& context, cl::Device& device){
    cl_int error = CL_SUCCESS;

    std::vector<float> data (512 * 1024 * 1024 / sizeof(float), 17.0f);
    auto const dataSizeInBytes = data.size() * sizeof(float);

    using Buffers = std::vector<cl::Buffer>;
    Buffers clBufferDstList;
    Buffers clBufferSrcList;

    cl::CommandQueue queue (context, device, 0, &error);
    if (CL_SUCCESS != error)
        return false;

    // Initialize main source buffer, will be cloned many times "inside the device"
    cl::Buffer clMainBufferSrc (context, 0, dataSizeInBytes, nullptr, &error);
    if (CL_SUCCESS != error)
        return false;
    error = queue.enqueueWriteBuffer (clMainBufferSrc, CL_TRUE, 0, dataSizeInBytes, data.data(), nullptr, nullptr);
    if (CL_SUCCESS != error)
        return false;

    // Loop until things break down
    while (true) {
        cl::Buffer clNewBufferSrc(context, 0, dataSizeInBytes, nullptr, &error);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != error)
            return false;
        cl::Buffer clNewBufferDst(context, 0, dataSizeInBytes, nullptr, &error);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != error)
            return false;
        clBufferSrcList.push_back(clNewBufferSrc);
        clBufferDstList.push_back(clNewBufferDst);

        // Copy data to new src and dst buffer - on the device / initialize buffers
        error = queue.enqueueCopyBuffer(clMainBufferSrc, clNewBufferSrc, 0, 0, dataSizeInBytes);
        if (CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE == error)
            break;
        if (CL_SUCCESS != error)
            return false;
        error = queue.enqueueCopyBuffer(clMainBufferSrc, clNewBufferDst, 0, 0, dataSizeInBytes);
        if (CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE == error)
            break;
        if (CL_SUCCESS != error)
            return false;
        error = queue.finish();
        if (CL_SUCCESS != error)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main() {
    // get all platforms (drivers), e.g. NVIDIA
    std::vector<cl::Platform> all_platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&all_platforms);

    if (all_platforms.size()==0) {
        std::cout<<" No platforms found. Check OpenCL installation!\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    cl::Platform default_platform=all_platforms[0];
    std::cout << "Using platform: "<<default_platform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>()<<"\n";

    // get default device (CPUs, GPUs) of the default platform
    std::vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
    default_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &all_devices);
    if(all_devices.size()==0){
        std::cout<<" No devices found. Check OpenCL installation!\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    // use device[1] because that's a GPU; device[0] is the CPU
    // or [0] if CPU has no ocl drivers
    cl::Device default_device=all_devices[0];
    std::cout<< "Using device: "<<default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>()<<"\n";

    DeviceData data;
    data.mContextCL = {default_device};

    auto f1 = [default_device, &data]() {
        // create a queue (a queue of commands that the GPU will execute)
        data.mQueueCL = {data.mContextCL, default_device};

        // create the program that we want to execute on the device
        cl::Program::Sources sources;

        // calculates for each element; C = A + B
        std::string kernel_code =
                "   void kernel simple_add(global const int* A, global const int* B, global int* C, "
                "                          global const int* N) {"
                "       int ID, Nthreads, n, ratio, start, stop;"
                ""
                "       ID = get_global_id(0);"
                "       Nthreads = get_global_size(0);"
                "       n = N[0];"
                ""
                "       ratio = (n / Nthreads);"  // number of elements for each thread
                "       start = ratio * ID;"
                "       stop  = ratio * (ID + 1);"
                ""
                "       for (int i=start; i<stop; i++)"
                "           C[i] = A[i] + B[i];"
                "   }";
        sources.push_back({kernel_code.c_str(), kernel_code.length()});

        data.mProgramCL = {data.mContextCL, sources};
        if (data.mProgramCL.build({default_device}) != CL_SUCCESS) {
            std::cout << "Error building: " << data.mProgramCL.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(default_device) << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        data.mKernelCL = {data.mProgramCL, "simple_add"};

        // create buffers on device (allocate space on GPU): A, B, C, N(1)
        data.mBufferListCL = {
                {data.mContextCL, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * data.n},
                {data.mContextCL, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * data.n},
                {data.mContextCL, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * data.n},
                {data.mContextCL, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,  sizeof(int)}
        };
    };

    auto f2 = [default_device, &data]() {
        // create things on here (CPU)
        int A[data.n], B[data.n];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.n; i++) {
            A[i] = i;
            B[i] = data.n - i - 1;
        }

        // apparently OpenCL only likes arrays ...
        // N holds the number of elements in the vectors we want to add
        int const N[1] = {data.n};

        auto& buffer_A = data.mBufferListCL[0];
        auto& buffer_B = data.mBufferListCL[1];
        auto& buffer_C = data.mBufferListCL[2];
        auto& buffer_N = data.mBufferListCL[3];

        // push write commands to queue
        data.mQueueCL.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_A, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * data.n, A);
        data.mQueueCL.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_B, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * data.n, B);
        data.mQueueCL.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_N, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int), N);

        // RUN ZE KERNEL
        data.mKernelCL.setArg(0, buffer_A);
        data.mKernelCL.setArg(1, buffer_B);
        data.mKernelCL.setArg(2, buffer_C);
        data.mKernelCL.setArg(3, buffer_N);
        data.mQueueCL.enqueueNDRangeKernel(data.mKernelCL, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(10), cl::NullRange);
        data.mQueueCL.finish();
    };

    auto f3 = [&data]() {
        auto &buffer_C = data.mBufferListCL[2];
        int C[data.n];
        // read result from GPU to here
        data.mQueueCL.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_C, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * data.n, C);

        std::cout << "result: {";
        for (int i = 0; i < data.n; i++) {
            std::cout << C[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
    };

    // First run to show that all is fine if we stay on the main thread

    produceError(data.mContextCL, default_device);

    f1();
    f2();
    f3();

    // Second run where we get stuck in t2, at the first data.mQueueCL.enqueueWriteBuffer() call.
    // It works if we uncomment the call to produceError() below.
    // It also works if we recreate the cl::Context again after the produceError() call.

    data = {};
    data.mContextCL = {default_device};

    produceError(data.mContextCL, default_device);

    auto t1 = std::thread(f1);
    auto t1_id = t1.get_id();
    t1.join();
    auto t2 = std::thread(f2);
    auto t2_id = t2.get_id();
    t2.join();
    auto t3 = std::thread(f3);
    auto t3_id = t3.get_id();
    t3.join();

    std::cout << t1_id << std::endl;
    std::cout << t2_id << std::endl;
    std::cout << t3_id << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```